# Printing 2d array initialized in a function but declared globally

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I am trying to print a 2d array that has been declared globally as a double pointer and initialized inside a function in `main()`, but I get a core dump error.
What am I doing wrong here?

The array stored in the file:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int** matrix_A = 0;

void initArray ( int** matrixPtr, FILE* matrixFP, int row, int col );


int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    FILE* matrixAfp = fopen ( argv[1], "r" );
    int M = atoi ( argv[3] );
    int N = atoi ( argv[4] );
    initArray ( matrix_A, matrixAfp, 3, 2 );
    for ( size_t m = 0; m < M; m++ )
    {
        for ( size_t n = 0; n < N; n++ )
        {
            printf ( "%d \n", matrix_A[m][n] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void initArray ( int** matrixPtr, FILE* matrixFP, int row, int col )
{
    matrixPtr = ( int** ) malloc ( row * sizeof ( int* ) );
    for ( size_t m = 0; m < row; m++ )
    {
        matrixPtr[m] = ( int* ) malloc ( col * sizeof ( int ) );
    }

    for ( size_t n = 0; n < row; n++ )
    {
        for ( size_t o = 0; o < col; o++ )
        {
            fscanf ( matrixFP, "%d", &matrixPtr[n][o] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are `M` and `N` defined?

Comment: Oh sorry I have more lines but i omitted them, M and N are command line arguments M is the number of rows and N columns. I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Move your `malloc()` in the `initArray()` to the `main()` can solve your problem.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the pointer by value, not by reference, so whatever you do with matrixPtr inside initArray will not make a difference outside the initArray-function. Try to modify the `initArray(FILE *matrixFP, int row, int col)` as followed,

```
int * initArray(FILE *matrixFP, int row, int col){
    int m,n,o;
    int **matrixPtr = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));

    for (m = 0; m < row; m++) {
        matrixPtr[m] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (n = 0; n < row; n++) {
        for (o = 0; o < col; o++) {
            fscanf(matrixFP, "%d", &matrixPtr[n][o]);
        }
    }
    return matrixPtr;
}
```

And using `matrix_A=initArray(matrixAfp, 3, 2);` in the `main()` to do the function call should work.

Comment: Dude thanks a lot the method should be int ** right then everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that since you're passing `matrix_A` to the function by-value, `matrixPtr` is actually a copy of the global `matrix_A`, which means all the changes inside the function are happening to `matrixPtr` and not to globally-defined `matrix_A`.

To solve this, you can instead pass it by-reference:
`void initArray(int** &matrixPtr, FILE *matrixFP, int row, int col)`

Apart from that, this:

```
int M = atoi(argv[3]);
int N = atoi(argv[4]);
```

should be:

```
int M = atoi(argv[2]);
int N = atoi(argv[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks I use argv[2] for something else this is not the complete code, changing the method signature to int ** worked.

Comment: Did you mean `int** &`?

Comment: no, I implemented what CWLiu suggested first and it worked but its int ** initArray(FILE *matrixFP, int row, int col);